# Bind Cassandra JMX to ip

Tags: cassandra, jmx

I'm using Cassandra 3.11.2 and I am unable to make the JMX bind on a specific interface.

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

netstat -l
tcp        0      0 *:7199                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

My cassandra-env.sh is as follows:

```
if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=no
fi

# Specifies the default port over which Cassandra will be available for
# JMX connections.
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
JMX_PORT="7199"

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  # if ssl is enabled the same port cannot be used for both jmx and rmi so either
  # pick another value for this property or comment out to use a random port (though see CASSANDRA-7087 for origins)
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.8.60"
fi
```

I was under the impression that Djava.rmi.server.hostname would set the jxm listen host. JMX connection does work fine in this situation.

EDIT:
It is now working but my connection is refused to the JMX host

```
root@server:/etc/cassandra# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:7199      *:*                     LISTEN

root@server:/etc/cassandra# nodetool -h 192.168.1.100 status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '192.168.1.100:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are looking for is:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=...
```

It has been added around jdk 1.8.0_101 so with the 1.8.0_171 you have it is ok.

Edit: The `port` need to be setup with

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=...
```

for this to work.

Also, as here you are using `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=...`, you need to either disable SSL or use one port for rmi and one for jmx.

One your use case, you can either have :

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=..."
```

or something like

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7200"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=..."
```

Comment: Still isn't setting it for me - listening on *

Comment: I add the full example with ssl/non ssl thing.

Comment: Thank you for the full example. It is now listening correctly but my connection is still refused by nodetool as in my edit. I suppose this is a separate question so I have rewarded the bounty as the answer worked. If you have any further advice let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The is no other error that 'connection refused' ?   Did you set a login password? if so you need to add authentication parameter with nodetool. (-u and -pw ). Did you set ssl ? ( with this you have 2 port, i never remember which one need to be specify)